# Calling a subclass function which does not exist on superclass

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

Say I have a class Person, and its subclass Boy. I want to include a method within Boy which Person **does not** have, and to be able to use through polymorphism in the following manner:

```
Boy john = Boy();
Person* personP = &john;

personP->boyFunction();
```

I've tried declaring the function in Person as virtual and =0 (in the header file). The problem is that I have multiple functions such as this one, and I don't want ALL subclasses to define ALL those functions.

How is this done neatly and safely, assuming I want to have multiple **different** subclasses of Person, each having a function exclusive to itself?

Comment: [Read this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). You don't get to break laws "neatly and safely", there's simply no such option.

Comment: If each function is exclusive to itself, why not just use plain old polymorphism and virtual functions? `class Person {public: virtual void Foo()=0;};`, `class Boy {public: virtual void Foo();};`, `class Girl {public: virtual void Foo();};`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have options. It depends on what exactly is the situation in which you want to call `boyFunction()`. If you know it *has* to be a `Boy*`, then you should require that you get a `Boy*`. Otherwise...

Most direct: the cast (though this is probably an indication of poor design), only call `boyFunction()` if applicable:

```
Boy* boy = dynamic_cast<Boy*>(personP);
if (boy) {
    boy->boyFunction();
}
```

Less direct, more pollution:

```
class Person {
   // ...
   virtual void boyFunction() { } // probably not = 0;
}

class Boy : public Person {
   // ...
   void boyFunction() { /* do stuff */ }
};

personP->boyFunction();
```

Why do you want to call `boyFunction()`? Maybe it's part of some larger algorithm... so wrap what you want to do in a larger dynamic method:

```
personP->performSomeFunction();
```

Where maybe:

```
void Boy::performSomeFunction() {
    a();
    b();
    boyFunction();
    c();
}
```

but

```
void Doctor::performSomeFunction() {
    doSurgery();
}
```